# How to add mouseover event to a dynamically generated html element by using setAttribute in angular 5

Tags: html, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, dom-manipulation

I actually want to add (mouseover)="sample()" to some html elements which are generated dynamically when the page loads in the browser

I tried to add the mouseover to the html element by using

```
document.querySelectorAll('idName ul li')[0].setAttribute('mouseover','sample()')
```

by executing the above code, the mouseover has been added to the dynamic html element in this way :

```
<li mouseover="sample()">First item</li>
```

But as I'm using angular 5 I need to wrap the mouseover event with parenthesis, which should look like

```
<li (mouseover)="sample()">First Item</li>
```

So, when I tried to include this in querySelector  :

```
document.querySelectorAll('idName ul li')[0].setAttribute('(mouseover)','sample()')
```

I'm getting an error saying that `(mouseover)` is not valid

How do I add this mouseover event to the html which is loaded dynamically.

I faced this situation when I tried to use the kendo multiselect box which just has this tag

```
 <kendo-multiselect [data]="data">
</kendo-multiselect>
```

The kendo multiselect ui looks like this [image]

Now to be clear when I hover on the selected options with close icon which are generated dynamically when the page loads in the browser (Baseball and Field Hockey) some function should be executed

Comment: The "angular way" is using templates https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/dropdowns/multiselect/templates/#toc-item-template In the template you can write, e.g. <span class="template" (mouseOver)="sample(dataitem)">{{ dataItem.text }}</span>

Comment: Thank you , I didn't see this option, will check this and let you know

Comment: Awesome!, that's working Thank you so much